# Terraform create a secret in aws secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

i would like create a secret with secret manager  aws

more precisely create a secret for docker registry.

I would like to  use terraform for that but i don't find a good code for that.

Does anyone have a concrete example

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the examples in the terraform [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/secretsmanager_secret_version)?

Comment: Just *create* the secret with terraform and set a value manually. Otherwise the secret is visible in the terraform state file and checked in in your source control, etc.

Comment: my container image  for aws fargate is in a private repository in docker hub ,

Comment: how to configure docker credential in the task definition 
in the most secure way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this work for you,

Firts create a secret in secretmanager:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secretregistry" {
   name = "registrycredentials"
}
```

Next add your registry credentials:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "sversion" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secretregistry.id
  secret_string = <<EOF
   {
    "username": "registryuser",
    "password": "Registrypass"
   }
EOF
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Please follow this link for extensive information about SSM though terraform
```

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter

You can use the following example

```
'resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "secret" {
   name        = "/production/database/password/master"
   description = "The parameter description"
   type        = "SecureString"
   value       = "secret_value"
   
   tags = {
   environment = "production"
   }
 }'
```

Comment: my problem was to activate in the task definition the private registry part and to associate this secret it's ok now

Comment: Glad to hear that.